# Drupal 6 Rules Execute custom php output not in html body

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I'm using drupal-6.22, rules-6.x-1.4, and some modules.
With the help of rules module, I've set a triggered rule, when the condition happens, it execute custom php code.
The custom PHP print some html like this:

```
<?php echo '<div><span><a href="whatever">whatever</a></span></div>'; ?>
```

BUT, the html just appears before the `!DOCTYPE html` tag, is there any method to place the code wherever I want?

```
(e.g. <div id="header">HERE!</div>)
```

I think in this case JS is in need, so I use `drupal_add_js($output,'inline')`, and called an outside function to place the html, still nothing happens.

I think there must be some method to let PHP insert the output into the current DOM tree, is there any known function or variables for this?

Please help, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/drupal_set_message) seems to be the right thing for you.